# Do I need to use "MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec" with "MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED" value?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

Is there any difference between 2 `measure` function calls?

1. `view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)`
2. `view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))`

In the debugger, I saw that the `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` equals to the `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)` but I am not sure if it's applicable to all Android SDK versions.

What is the more conventional way to pass an argument to the `measure` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[View.MeasureSpec#UNSPECIFIED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec#UNSPECIFIED) is equal to zero. You are also encoding a zero width in your example. [View.MeasureSpec#makeMeasureSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec#makeMeasureSpec(int,%20int)) encodes these two values into an int, so the result is zero. (You can look at the `makeMeasureSpec()` code to see how this is done.

[View#measure(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#measure(int,%20int)) calls [View#onMeasure(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onMeasure(int,%20int)).

> The actual measurement work of a view is performed in onMeasure(int, int), called by this method. Therefore, only onMeasure(int, int) can and must be overridden by subclasses.

The arguments for `onMeasure()` are *widthMeasureSpec*:

> int: horizontal space requirements as imposed by the parent. The requirements are encoded with View.MeasureSpec.
>
> heightMeasureSpec  int: vertical space requirements as imposed by the parent. The requirements are encoded with View.MeasureSpec.

Follow the encoding advice above and you will be make well-formed measurements calls even when the width/height is other than zero.